# Own changes in CloudFoundry development environment not visible to me only

Tags: cloud-foundry, sap-fiori

For the past week I've been dealing with a peculiar issue. I deployed changes to the specific application in the CloudFoundry dev environment as usual. My initial small XML change showed up fine. After that I tried making further changes that have not shown up despite persistent attempts. These changes don't seem to there either visually or in the code.

What's weird is that my changes are visible to my two colleagues. Likewise, the changes to other applications on the launchpad I have made after this are displayed normally.

I've tried any number of combinations of the usual things that have worked before; deleted cache and refreshed, deleted all local storage and sessions, logged out and logged back in. I have rebooted the computer several times and I've even downloaded a new browser to try it on. Nothing has worked.

Any idea what might be the cause and/or how to resolve the issue?